# .net 7 dynamically loaded code - how to print to debug window?

Tags: c#, dynamic, .net-7.0

I have dynamically compiled C# code which then loaded in `AssemblyLoadContext`.

This works. There is one method in it and it is called and returns value as expected.

However in future these will be more complicated. I want to be able to find a way to log some info from inside this dynamic code.

I tried Debug and Trace - nothing is printed (although as I said I am sure the method had been called).

So how would you output information from dynamically loaded dll in VS or another way? Something that can be routinely used?

Comment: pass some kind of logging class that can be used from within the dynamic code?

Comment: good idea certainly give it a try